# Spring Cloud Sleuth exited without errors/warnings

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am following the site [here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-sleuth#overview) and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-sleuth-single-application), to use Spring Cloud Sleuth, but the application exited without any warning/ errors.

i have added the depedency to build.gradle:

`compile ('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:1.0.0.RELEASE')`

i have tried to exclude the commons-logging as mentioned [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12816):

```
compile ('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:1.0.0.RELEASE')
{ 
     exclude module: 'commons.logging'
     exclude group: 'commons.logging'
}
```

But still no luck. Here is the console output:

> 11:57:31.952 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging
>   Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4j2LoggerProvider 11:57:31.956
>   [background-preinit] INFO
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate
>   Validator 6.0.11.Final 11:57:31.975 [background-preinit] DEBUG
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraversableResolvers
>   - Found javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath containing 'getPersistenceUtil'. Assuming JPA 2 environment. Trying to
>   instantiate JPA aware TraversableResolver 11:57:31.976
>   [background-preinit] DEBUG
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraversableResolvers
>   - Instantiated JPA aware TraversableResolver of type org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
>   11:57:31.980 [background-preinit] DEBUG
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationXmlParser -
>   Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml for XML based Validator
>   configuration. 11:57:31.981 [background-preinit] DEBUG
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ResourceLoaderHelper -
>   Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via TCCL 11:57:31.982
>   [background-preinit] DEBUG
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ResourceLoaderHelper -
>   Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via Hibernate Validator's class
>   loader 11:57:31.982 [background-preinit] DEBUG
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationXmlParser - No
>   META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration
>   only. 11:57:32.145 [background-preinit] DEBUG
>   org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator
>   - Loaded expression factory via original TCCL 11:57:32.152 [background-preinit] DEBUG
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl -
>   HV000234: Using
>   org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator
>   as ValidatorFactory-scoped message interpolator. 11:57:32.152
>   [background-preinit] DEBUG
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl -
>   HV000234: Using
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver
>   as ValidatorFactory-scoped traversable resolver. 11:57:32.152
>   [background-preinit] DEBUG
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl -
>   HV000234: Using
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ExecutableParameterNameProvider
>   as ValidatorFactory-scoped parameter name provider. 11:57:32.152
>   [background-preinit] DEBUG
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl -
>   HV000234: Using
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.DefaultClockProvider as
>   ValidatorFactory-scoped clock provider. 11:57:32.152
>   [background-preinit] DEBUG
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl -
>   HV000234: Using
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.scripting.DefaultScriptEvaluatorFactory
>   as ValidatorFactory-scoped script evaluator factory.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

**UPDATES**

I have updated the dependency to

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-sleuth', version: '2.1.0.RELEASE'
```

But the application still cannot start, here are the logs:

```
2019-02-13 15:45:25.001  INFO [-,,,] 20148 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@20deea7f: startup date [Wed Feb 13 15:45:24 HKT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-02-13 15:45:25.345  INFO [-,,,] 20148 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$adc7b00a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.4.RELEASE)

2019-02-13 15:45:25.551  INFO [-,,,] 20148 --- [           main] c.s.m.ABCServiceApplication       : The following profiles are active: dev

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Provided logs are not enough to understand what's happening in your app. Add more logs and code

Comment: i would like to provide more logs but these are the only messages from the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Sleuth in an ancient version. Can you please use the latest one? Go to start.spring.io and generate a spring boot project with sleuth. That way you won't have to configure anything by yourself.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I have updated the version, please see the "updates" section in the question. thanks

Comment: You're using a wrong version of boot. 2.0.4 should go with Finchley release train (2.0.x of sleuth). Either downgrade boot or upgrade sleuth

Comment: Thank you Marcin Grzejszczak for the comments, I have updated the sleuth to `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:2.1.0.RELEASE`, is that what you mean?

Comment: Thanks, `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:2.0.2.RELEASE` works as expected.